# Process to call Fortran executable from C#

Tags: c#, process

I have a fortran executable that I'm trying to run with a process. The fortran executable requests a file from the user, performs an operation to find a solution, and afterwards if there are multiple solutions, it will ask the user if the would like to find the most optimal solution. My code here that I have provided seems to always crash when I call wait for input idle, as there doesn't seem to be a gui. I'm new to using processes so if someone could help me out, that would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit: I forgot to mention that the fortran executable generates a text file after to provide results to the user. When I remove the wait for input idle, it no longer crashes but the resulting text file is no longer generated. Is the executable not running properly?

```
        Process exeProcess = new Process();
        exeProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"...\marcus12.exe";
        exeProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        exeProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        exeProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        exeProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        exeProcess.Start();
        //exeProcess.WaitForInputIdle();
        exeProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(filePath));
        //exeProcess.WaitForInputIdle();
        exeProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("Y");
        exeProcess.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: You don't need to wait at all.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, it no longer crashes, but now the executable is not generating correct outputs (see edit), which makes me question if it is being run properly at all.

Comment: Read the standard out & error and see what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WaitForInputIdle() is used when the process you launch is a Windows application with message loop. In your case it's simple console application.

Therefore all you need is to exclude two WaitForInputIdle() calls from the code:

```
Process exeProcess = new Process();
exeProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"...\marcus12.exe";
exeProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
exeProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
exeProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
exeProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
exeProcess.Start();
exeProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(filePath));
exeProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("Y");
exeProcess.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the two `exeProcess.WaitForInputIdle();` lines, they are not necessary in your case.